# How to display ICollection<T> not equal to null in a Get request ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two models and two dtos, and I want to know if there's any way to display all the collection values in the get request?

Model `Estado`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppEstados.Models
{
    public class Estado
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Municipio>? Municipios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model `Municipio`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppEstados.Models
{
    public class Municipio
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public  string? Nombre { get; set; }

        public int EstadoId { get; set; }

        public Estado? Estado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`EstadoDto`:

```
using AppEstados.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppEstados.DTOs
{
    public class EstadoDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Municipio>? Municipios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MunicipioDto`:

```
using AppEstados.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppEstados.DTOs
{
    public class MunicipioDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Nombre { get; set; }

        public int EstadoId { get; set; }

        public string? Estado { get; set; }
      
    }
}
```

`EstadoController`:

```
// GET: api/Estado
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EstadoDto>>> GetEstados()
{              
    var listaEstados = await _context.Estados
                                     .Include(x => x.Municipios)
                                     .Select(x => new EstadoDto
                                                  {
                                                      Id = x.Id,
                                                      Nombre = x.Nombre,
                                                      Municipios = x.Municipios                    
                                                  })
                                     .ToListAsync();
            
    return listaEstados;
}
```

`MunicipioController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MunicipioDto>>> GetMunicipios()
{
    var municipio = await _context.Municipios
                                  .Select(x => new MunicipioDto
                                               {
                                                   Id = x.Id,
                                                   Nombre = x.Nombre,
                                                   EstadoId = x.EstadoId,
                                                   Estado = x.Estado.Nombre
                                               })
                                  .ToListAsync();

     return municipio;
}
```

As you can see, I get all of the values for `municipio`, except the
`Estado` field which for some reason is returned as null. Do I have
to be more specific with my dto, or is there a way for that field, to
not equal to null?

[image: Get request For estado]

It is worth mentioning that if a send a get request to the `Municipio`
do get all the list of records.

[image: Get request for municipio]

---

### Solution

---

```
// GET: api/Estado
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EstadoDto>>> GetEstados()
{

    var listaEstados = await _context.Estados
        .Select(x => new EstadoDto
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Nombre = x.Nombre,
            Municipios = x.Municipios.Select(m => new MunicipioDto
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                Nombre = m.Nombre,
                EstadoId = m.EstadoId,
                Estado = m.Estado.Nombre
            }).ToList()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
    return listaEstados;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `public ICollection<Municipio>? Municipalities { get; set; }` use ``public ICollection<MunicipioDto>? Municipalities { get; set; }`` in `EstadoDto`

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh   i followed your suggestion, but didnt work... ;c

Comment: Why didn't it work? what is your problem

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh it keeps showing null , for the field estado in the municipios subsets... i am going to create a more specific dto... to display all the data... i thought this could be done with i collection..

Comment: ok i give up... i think its not possible load child entitie values from the parent entity... since this is one to many relation ... Estado.------>Municipio.

Answer (score 0):

In `EstadoDto` make this change

`public ICollection<MunicipioDto>? Municipios { get; set; }`

And change the fetch method to

```
var listaEstados = await _context.Estados
                                     .Select(x => new EstadoDto
                                                  {
                                                      Id = x.Id,
                                                      Nombre = x.Nombre,
                                                      Municipios = x.Select(m => new MunicipioDto
                                               {
                                                   Id = m.Id,
                                                   Nombre = m.Nombre,
                                                   EstadoId = m.EstadoId,
                                                   Estado = m.Estado.Nombre
                                               }).ToList()                    
                                                  })
                                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks WisdomoSeeker, how could i learn more advanced querys like these ? Any reference ?

Comment: Glad I could help. A good place to start is the official Microsoft documentation. It covers EF in depth. The information might be a little scattered. Look for references like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/linq-in-csharp